# Upgrading from RoR 4.2 to 5.1 - seeing an array element "[...]" in ActiveModel::Errors messages array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Was upgrading from Rails 4.2 to Rail 5 and ran into a deprecation error:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveModel::Errors#set is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use model.errors.add(:foo, ["is required"]) instead.

Ok, easy enough. So I changed it to `model.errors.add(:foo, ['message'])`, however then one of my specs started going into an infinite loop (from what I could tell it was due to an self-referencing array passed to a render and then a `to_json` method).

So, I threw in a pry and noticed the errors on my model include a strange `[...]` element:

```
["is required", [...]]
```

The above happens when I call the `add` method vs the `set` method. The `set` method on the other hand just returns `["is required"]` -- without the 2nd `[...]` element. When I try to reference that element - it just returns the whole array:

```
> result.second
=> ["is required", [...]]
```

Another interesting find is that when I call `object_id` on it, it points to the parent array:

```
> result.object_id
=> 47158376546320
> result.second.object_id
=> 47158376546320
```

So my question is:

1. Why is the `add` method adding a second array element that's just a reference to the array itself?

Note: for reference I'm actually on 5.0.6, haven't upgraded to 5.1 yet.

Comment: As per https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add, maybe try using the `message` key, `message: "is required"`.

Answer (score 0):

The messages were stored in a local variable which directly referred to the error instance which also caused an infinite loop. I decided to duplicate it and then iterate over the array to add each message separately:

```
messages.dup.each { |m| record.errors.add(attribute, message: m) }
```

That seemed to do it!